# Cron shell ignores runuser command - why?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, cron, users

I have two bash scripts. One runs as root, and it calls another one as user "parallels"

/root/cronrun.sh

```
#! /bin/bash

PARR="thisparameter"

echo "Starting at `date`" >> /root/rlog.log
runuser -l parallels -c "/home/parallels/testscript/newscript.sh $PARR"
echo "Finishing at `date`" >> /root/rlog.log
```

/home/parallels/testscript/newscript.sh

```
#! /bin/bash

PARAMM=$1

echo "`date` - newscript.sh ran with $PARAMM" >> /home/parallels/somelog.log
```

Ran /root/cronrun.sh from command line as root at

```
18:17:28 CET 
18:17:29 CET
```

Added to crontab

```
*/2 * * * * /root/cronrun.sh
```

So it ran at 18:20:00 CET via cron

After this:

/root/rlog.log

```
Starting at Thu Nov 16 18:17:28 CET 2017
Finishing at Thu Nov 16 18:17:28 CET 2017
Starting at Thu Nov 16 18:17:29 CET 2017
Finishing at Thu Nov 16 18:17:29 CET 2017
Starting at Thu Nov 16 18:20:01 CET 2017
Finishing at Thu Nov 16 18:20:01 CET 2017
```

/home/parallels/somelog.log

```
Thu Nov 16 18:17:28 CET 2017 - newscript.sh ran with thisparameter
Thu Nov 16 18:17:29 CET 2017 - newscript.sh ran with thisparameter
```

So the log entry from the echo in the runuser shell is missing. Why it can be possible? How does cron run differently in this case, which makes "runuser" command ignored/failed?

(System reproduced on is Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS)

(SHELL=/bin/bash in crontab is not solving it)

Comment: for the first 2 runs yes (via command line). The 3rd run was via cron, and then it didn't run, only the line before and after

Comment: and more importantly SHELL=/bin/bash adding to crontab is not solving it, just tried

Comment: Could cron's $PATH not have `runuser` in it, while your interactive shell does?

Comment: have the cronrun.sh script echo $PATH and also echo $? after the runuser command -- all to the rlog.log

Comment: Please send this as an answer and I'll accept it Jeff - replacing it to /sbin/runuser solved it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cron runs with a specific PATH, as seen in the upstream Debian [source code](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-cron/pkg-cron.git/tree/pathnames.h):

```
#ifndef _PATH_DEFPATH
# define _PATH_DEFPATH "/usr/bin:/bin"
#endif
```

Referenced [here](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-cron/pkg-cron.git/tree/cron.c#n97):

```
#if defined(POSIX)
    setenv("PATH", _PATH_DEFPATH, 1);
#endif
```

and since `runuser` lives in /sbin, you'll need to use the full path to it, or set PATH in your script to include /sbin.

Comment: thanks (actually /sbin/runuser , but yes, this solved it )